# Ajax-TabPanel error: make sure the AjaxToolkit.Properties.Resources.NET4.resources are properly imbedded or linked to assembly

Tags: asp.net

I get an error in the design window of asp.net when using ajaxToolkit:TabPanel.  It is inside the container.  The error message says:

> "...make sure the AjaxToolkit.Properties.Resources.NET4.resources are
>   properly imbedded or linked to assembly...."

My aspx markup:

```
<asp:TableRow>
  <asp:TableCell runat="server" Width="100%">
    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" 
        Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#336699" 
        Font-Names="Arial" Height="150" Width="100%">
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Inset" 
              BorderWidth="2" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" 
              ForeColor="#336699" HeaderText="Metric1" Height="150px" runat="server" Width="100%">
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
  </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

I have tried several things already: AjaxtToolKit.ScriptManager, added reference to `AjaxToolKit.dll`, and registered AjaxToolKit at top of aspx page.

I am just trying to insert a tab tool to the web page I am working on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to add ToolkitScriptManager  instead of ScriptManager

Comment: I did that - still does not work.